# How to initiate screen saver when locking mac osx

Tags: macos

Currently when I leave my desk I lock my screen and that turns off the monitor and then when I return and move the mouse I need to enter my password.

The problem is I never get to see my screensaver when I return.

How do I have the security of locking the screen but instead of turning off the monitor is should immediately go into screensaver mode.  Then when I move the mouse it must exit screensaver and request password.

Similar to Windows XP

Comment: What OS are you currently running? You specify that you want your current OS to behave like Windows XP, but not what your current OS is. EDIT: noticed the OSX tag. Should probably mention that in the post body...

Comment: @Jeremy Question title and tag seems sufficient to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your scrensaver settings configured to lock the machine when the screensaver activates, simply manually activating your screensaver (e.g., by a hot corner) should leave your desktop "locked" in that deactivating the screensaver should request a password.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your screensaver to require a password to unlock again in *System Preferences » Security*:

[image]

---

In *System Preferences » Desktop & Screen Saver » Screen Saver* you can configure your screen saver, after how long it should appear, and even *Hot Corners* of your screen, where moving the mouse there would activate your screen saver.
[image]

---

Another way to start your screen saver is to execute the following application:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app
```

This application starts the screen saver. Put it in your Dock, your Finder's sidebar or toolbar, start with your preferred application launcher, Automator Service, AppleScript or whatever you want.

Comment: Pretty nice setup, FYI for Monterey it's has been changed to 
`/System/Library/CoreServices/ScreenSaverEngine.app`