# Set lock image on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

On Mac OS you can lock your system using CTRL+Shift+Eject button. But when I do that the background image is empty or blank. How can I set a background image on locking Mac ?.

Comment: As an alternative, consider starting [the screen saver instead](http://superuser.com/questions/238861/how-to-initiate-screen-saver-when-locking-mac-osx/238870#238870). You might be able to find one (or create a new one) that simply displays an image, not movement at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command puts the display to sleep. There's no way to display an image with the display turned off.

Comment: True! (Though I assume that when requiring a password after sleep, the login screen will show?)

Comment: @Arjan [It doesn't seem possible](http://superuser.com/questions/248768/is-it-possible-to-change-the-background-behind-the-os-x-login-box-screen-saver-un/248963#248963).